# SQL Server Stored Procedure with a FileName variable

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am having some serious problems with loading data from xml file. I want to declare it as a procedure with the .xml file name as parameter.

```
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE loadXML 
@FileName varchar(50)
AS
 BEGIN 
    DECLARE @XML AS XML,@hDoc AS INT
    SELECT @XML = CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) 
    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'D:\ '+@FileName , SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;

    EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML

    INSERT  INTO [dbo].[Client]
    SELECT *
    FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'orderType/client')

    WITH
    (
         OrderId varchar(200) '../../../sn',
         Client_number varchar(200) 'client_number',
         FirstName varchar(200) 'firstname', 
         LastName varchar(200) 'lastname', 
         E-Mail varchar(200) 'email'   
    )

   EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc   

END

exec loadXML 'order2.xml'
```

Obviously, this code won't work, because there's a syntax error near the @FilePath variable. I tried making string variables with the whole SELECT part, but it didn't work.

Comment: `FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ' + 'D:\'+@FileName'' , SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;`? I'd say your single quotes are messed up. Oh, and please post the exact error message.

Comment: Ok, I cleaned up the mess with quotes, thanks. The error I receive with this particular code is: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure loadXML, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near '+'.

Comment: You can't concat like that way. best is to pass the entire path as parameter as I have mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't pass the entire path along with drive name as parameter. I mean `D:\folder1\file.xml`.

Assuming that `@FileName` parameter has the full path like `D:\folder1\file.xml` then you can use dynamic query to achieve what you are looking for like below. Give it a try

```
DECLARE @sqlCommand varchar(1000)
SET @sqlCommand = 'set @XML = (SELECT '+ @XML + ' = CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) 
    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ' + @FileName +' , SINGLE_BLOB) AS x)';

declare @xml xml;

EXEC sp_executesql @sqlCommand, N'@XYZ xml output', @xml output


EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XYZ;

 //rest of the code here
```

Comment: When i put the variable inside the OPENROWSET it won't work because of
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure loadXML, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near '@FileName'.

Comment: Still nothing. 
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure loadXML, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure stack, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
Procedure won't be created and BulkColumn, your SELECT and SINGLE_BLOB are underlined.

Comment: @PRHMN, edited my answer. You can use dynamic query. give it a try.

Comment: Yea, managed to deal with that. My code is slighly different, but the idea is common. Thanks for all the efort! :)